# Clear a div tag that is refilled with a table created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My page is used to create a base-6 table of numbers that highlight prime numbers. The user inputs the number that they want the table to end in, and a script generates the table. It does it in a div tag with the id "tablearea."

The problem is that if the user inputs a new number and submits, the second table is added at the bottom of the first. What I want is for the first table to be cleared, and subsequent requested tables to be written in the same area. How do I accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<!-- This page asks the user to input a number to search for primes and returns a base-6 table with primes highlighted -->
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="prime numbers, prime, primes, prime twins">

<title>Prime Numbers</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

/* This function determines if a number is prime or not */
function isPrime(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1 || n<2) return false; 
 if (n%2==0) return (n==2);
 if (n%3==0) return (n==3);
 var m=Math.sqrt(n);
 for (var i=5;i<=m;i+=6) {
  if (n%i==0)     return false;
  if (n%(i+2)==0) return false;
 }
 return true;
}

/* This function creates the table and color codes the cells of prime numbers */
function tableCreate(X){

    var numCheck = X;
    var numRow = numCheck/6;
    var numCell = 1;
    var body = document.body;
    var tbl  = document.createElement('table');


    for(var i = 0; i < numRow; i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow(-1);
        for(var j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            if(i==numRow && j==6 || numCheck==numCell-1){
                    break
            } 
            else {
                var td = tr.insertCell(-1);
                if(isPrime(numCell) == true){
                    td.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
                }
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(numCell)); 
                numCell++;
            }
        }
    }
    body.appendChild(tbl).tablearea;
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    <!-- td {border: 1px solid black} -->
    table{width: 50%; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto}

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <form name="primes">
    <p style="text-align: center">How many numbers would you like to check for primes?&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="nums">
    <input type="button" value="Check'em!" onClick="tableCreate(document.primes.nums.value)">
    <input type="reset">
    </p>
    </form>
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="tablearea">
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the contents of the div before you insert a table with different content to the same div

Just replace the below line in your code

```
    body.appendChild(tbl).tablearea;
```

with

```
document.getElementById("tablearea").innerHTML='';

document.getElementById("tablearea").appendChild(tbl);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. After reading RobG's answer, I realized my bonehead mistake. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the table to appear in the div with ID *tablearea*, you need to do something like:

```
var div = document.getElementById('tablearea');
div.appendChild(tbl);
```

If you then want to replace the table with a new one, there are lots of options, but the easiest is probably to empty the div and insert the new table:

```
div.innerHTML = '';
div.appendChild(tbl);
```

If you have other content in the div that you don't want to destroy, then replace just the table:

```
var oldTable = div.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

// If there's an existing table, replace it
if (oldTable) {
  div.replaceChild(tbl, oldTable);

// If there wasn't, just append the new one
} else {
  div.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

Comment: The second block helped. I realized my mistake and was actually typing the second answer in as it was posted. Thanks.